# How can I read files from a camera attached via usb

Tags: c#, winforms, usb

In C# how can I copy a file from a camera to my local drive? The camera is connected via USB and it does not show up as a standard drive.

I am using a Sony Handycam  HDR-CX160. I want to write a small c# windowsform app that copies the video files from the device.

So how does my app copy files from the device connected via usb? It does not show up as a drive but it shows up in windows explorer. When I search drives in C# it is not in the list?

Thanks!

======== UPDATE =======

I am going to try and ask this question a different way and hopefully it will get reopened.

Using C# I need to copy a file from a camera to my local hard drive. If I new the path this line of code would do it.

```
string cameraPath = ?????
string sourcePath = Path.Combine(cameraPath, @"\Video\2012-1-1.WMV");
string targetPath =  @"C:\Video\2012-1-1.WMV";
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

So how can I resolve the cameraPath? Is there another way to do this all together?

Comment: This question is too broad. It would be be best to come back once you are stuck on a specific aspect of your project.

Comment: Not sure why there is a vote to close? This is a real c# issue I cannot find an answer too. I just need a programmatic way to connect to a device so I can copy a file from it.

Comment: this is about usb drives but maybe you will find something useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program

Comment: @JameyMcElveen I think you should determine the root path for that windows-explorer folder first. (e.g. `E:\\`)

Comment: @Desolator It is not a drive at all I tested all drives before I asked the question here. So a way to determine the "root path" would answer my question :)

Comment: I tried to clarify more please help reopen.

Comment: @JameyMcElveen +1 Your question is very interesting and I am interested in seeing the result. I initially voted to close your question (did not downvote) before you had made your first edit, however, with this most recent edit made to your question, it is much more apparent and very specific. I have voted to open it back up. Good luck finding the answer you need!

Comment: @JoshMein Thanks!! whrn I get it working I will post the code

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the specifics about your device and the best bet is probably to use the software that came with your device.

However, if a digital camera doesn't present itself as a drive that you can read files from it may support [Windows Image Acquisition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . The easiest way to use that from C# is to use [Windows Image Acquisition Automation Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Scott Hanselman has an old Coding4Fun article [Look at me! Windows Image Acquisition](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition) on Channel 9.

If you are able to remove the flash memory card from the camera you can also try to read this card using a card reader to get direct access to the files.

Also, if you want to run your application when you connect the camera you need to [register an AutoPlay event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa468474.aspx). There is an event for when a camera is connected.

Comment: I am still researching but WIA put me on a path I hope will lead to the answer. Thanks!